# How can I repeat a value in a list variable for coloring bar charts in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to search for something but I don't know the correct words to find my answer (if it exists).

I am trying to color the bars on a barchart with 24 bars using this: https://python-graph-gallery.com/3-control-color-of-barplots/

I want to color bars 0-15 one color, and bars 16-23 another color. I was wondering if there's a way I can make a variable called "my_colors" and a list without actually repeating a hexcode over and over 24x. I only need 2 colors in my list repeated a bunch of times...

Is there some notation to write this sort of list?

Comment: Loop through the bars with an index (e.g. using `enumerate`). `If index < 16: color = (...) else: color = (...)`

Comment: Oh thank you. I am not too familiar with how to do that, as I don't know how to reference the bars correctly. Initially I tried saying something like bars[0:15] and just coloring that way in two lines (my bars are called 'bars')

Comment: I think in the end this is what I did: `my_colors = []
for x in range(15):
    my_colors.append('#0066ff')
for x in range(9):
    my_colors.append('#ff0000')` it might not be the best way to do this but list comprehension is what I wanted to do I guess...

Comment: if you are using matplotlib object oriented interface, which is something like this `fig, ax = plt.subplots(...)`, you can access each of the bar (known as patch) plotted in `ax` using a for loop like this `for patch in ax.patches`, followed by `patch.set_color(your_color)`. If you need more help, edit your question with a minimal reproducible dataframe & your code, so that the question is clearer.

Comment: Ohh thanks a lot. I did not know that's how you do that. I was looking for the list multiplication solution, but this really helps with other things I may need to do later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your colors are in blocks, you can just do list multiplication:

```
# define the colors
my_colors = ['#AAAA00', '#DD00DD']
colors = my_colors[:1]*15 + my_colors[1:] * 9

# toy data
np.random.seed(1)
plt.bar(np.arange(24),
        np.random.randint(1,10,24),
        color=colors)
```

Output

[image]

Comment: ahhh thanks a lot! that's exactly what i was looking for.